# 5VDC 4mA to 5V 200mA

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

Arduino gives a PWM output of 5V dc 4mA, the requirement of my project is 5V 200mA. how do I boost current from 4mA to 200mA by keeping voltage as 5V as the signal is a digital signal?

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack. Please take the tour (find it under the help link at the top). Consider searching the site before asking.  Hint: with a "buffer". Search the site for "buffer", "power transistor", "amplifier". You may use "[tags]" (brackets around tag names to search for tags).

Comment: A common collector or emitter-follower stage will drop the voltage slightly but provide large current drive. The lower voltage is usually still at an acceptable level. As you have not proi=vided any details about the load we cannot tell what level your load REALLY needs. "Digita; signal" is not enough information. See [Wikipedia rewf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) and [many of these](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=emitter+follower&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimh93J8oTSAhUHGZQKHafaD7UQ_AUICCgB&biw=1866&bih=1022)

Comment: the load is a servo motor. the signal provided by the arduino is a pwm signal and connot provide enough power to drive the motor.

Comment: So then search for "Arduino servo motor" and see what pops up.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that your 5V PWM really delivers power to the servo motor. More commonly in the hobby domain (no offense intended) is the following 3-wire arangement: constant 5V/200mA power, ground plus a 3.3V/5V PWM logic signal (negligible current) to transmit the desired servo position.